# Check if integer is positive in ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm trying to make users input a positive integer(>=1). If the user inputs a negative integer or 0, the program gonna notice and say you didn't put a valid integer, please try again. my program works so far until I try to input a string. My program break after I input a string. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I tried elsif !barsofsoap.match (/\A[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+\Z/)
    puts "You didn't enter an integer, please put a positive integer", but it didn't work

```
loop do
  puts "How many soaps are you looking to purchase? (Please put an integer)"
  x = gets.chomp
  barsofsoap = Integer(x) rescue false

  if barsofsoap >= 1
    break
  else
    puts "You didn't put an integer, please put an integer and try again."
  end
end
```

I hope the program will not break if the user inputs a string.

Comment: `if barsofsoap >= 1` is in fact the right way to check this. `match` would work for a String type, but your `barsofsoap = Integer(x)` ensures that you're dealing with a numeric type. Try it again!

Comment: @Chris Heald  if barsofsoap >= 1 works, but if I input a string, the program will break, I guess my problem is how to make the program not break if I put a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your current code fails is because you use `false` as rescue value. You can't compare `false >= 1`. Sticking close to your original code you might wrap the comparison into a `begin`/`end` block.

```
loop do
  puts "How many soaps are you looking to purchase? (Please put an integer)"
  x = gets.chomp
  begin
    barsofsoap = Integer(x)
    if barsofsoap >= 1
      break
    end
  rescue ArgumentError => _error
    puts "You didn't put an integer, please put an integer and try again."
  end
end
```

Or simplifying the code:

```
loop do
  puts "How many soaps are you looking to purchase? (Please put an integer)"
  break if (barsofsoap = gets.to_i).positive?
  puts "Invalid input. Provide a positive integer."
end
```

The above code doesn't detect if the input is a string or an integer. By replacing `Integer(x)` with `x.to_i` it would simply return `0` if invalid. Since you want the user to provide an positive integer it still requests them to provide a new integer.

```
nil.to_i #=> 0
''.to_i #=> 0
'asdf'.to_i #=> 0
'12.34'.to_i #=> 12
```

Like shown above the string `'12.34'` will produce the value `12`. Depending on your requirements you might not want to use this value and instead mark it as invalid input. In this case you could use a regex to check the provided input.

```
loop do
  puts "How many soaps are you looking to purchase? (Please put an integer)"
  input = gets
  break barsofsoap = input.to_i if input.match?(/\A[1-9]\d*\Z/)
  puts "Invalid input. Provide a positive integer."
end
```

The regex `/\A[1-9]\d*\Z/` will match the following:

- `\A` Matches start of string.
- `[1-9]` Matches one of the digits `1-9`.
- `\d*` Matches zero or more digits `0-9`.
- `\Z` Matches end of string. If the string ends with a newline, it matches just before the newline.

Comment: The `.to_i` method is more idiomatic Ruby since any object which responds to `.to_i` is valid (Duck Typing) instead of forcing it down `Integer` and hoping it works out.

Comment: @Leslie I've updated the answer to only allow the numbers 1 through 4. See the new code block.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Sorry, that was a typo, I want the number to be 1 to infinity

Answer (score 7):

You try this: `num.positive?`

see here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Numeric.html#method-i-positive-3F

Also you can try convert the text to an integer and validate by doing this:
`num.is_a?(Integer)`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F

Or even better since input is always text, you can use a regex to make sure only numbers are entered: `"12345" =~ /\A\d+\Z/`

How about try this:

```rb
loop do
  puts "How many soaps are you looking to purchase? (Please put an integer)"

  barsofsoap = gets.chomp

  if barsofsoap.match(/^[\d]+$/).nil?
    puts "You didn't put an integer, please put an integer and try again."
  elsif barsofsoap.to_i.positive?
    break
  else
    puts "You didn't put an integer, please put an integer and try again."
  end
end
```

Comment: That's works, but if I input a string, the program will break, I try to find some way that the program will not break even I put a string.

Comment: Why do you check twice here? `if barsofsoap >= 0 && barsofsoap.positive?`

Comment: @Zach Tuttle  Thanks for your answer.  I tried this before, but if I input a decimal number, the program will think it's an integer and keep going, I don't want users to input a float.

Comment: @Leslie just call the #floor method to drop the decimal all together. Please see updated example.

Comment: @Zach Tuttle I tried. the program will still keep going when I input a decimal number

Comment: @Leslie This is what #floor does, for example if you enter in 3.2 it then becomes 3.

Comment: @Zach Tuttle Thanks for your answer. but I guess I don't want the user to input decimal number, I want the system to tell users they can't input decimal number.

Comment: @Leslie Okay I added an extra check to make sure that only whole numbers and entered then that is followed by another to ensure that is a non-negative number. Please see the updated example.

Answer (score 2):

Other option, using `n.to_i.to_s == n` to check the input is an Integer and moving the loop into a method:

```
def get_input_integer
  loop do
    puts "Enter a positive Integer"
    n = gets.chomp
    if n.to_i.to_s == n
      return n.to_i if n.to_i.positive?
      puts "It's not positive"
    else
      puts "It's not an integer" 
    end
  end
end

x = get_input_integer
```